# python regex sub repeat specific pattern

Tags: python, regex

i have some string data that contains characters from color coding.. i am trying to remove them using re.sub , but i can't figure out how to repeat my pattern. i thought +? would as it states 1 or more repetitions non-greedy. but it is only removing the "[0m" in the string not also the "[32m"

```
test = 'test1 test2                       [32mOK[0m'
test = re.sub(r'(.\[[\d*]m)+?', '', test)
```

how do make a regex that will remove any instance of the combination above leaving the text in between which in this instance is "OK" ??

my end goal here is to leave the OK text that is between [32 and [0m... OK could say FAILED or ERROR like this [32mFAILED[0m, [32mERROR[0m

Answer (score 3):

You can try using the following pattern:

```
test = re.sub(r'(?:\[\d+m)', '', test)
```

This says to match `[` followed by any number of digits, followed by `m`.  Note that this would leave intact any content after the `m`.

### Demo

Comment: Should be `.strip()`?

Comment: @andrew_reece Thanks...it was working in the demo, somehow never got copied over.

Comment: Sorry please re-read my post, I need the "OK" text to remain, that was my issue all along i couldn't fig out how to regex to just remove the "[32m" and the "[0m"  , where the 32 and 0 might change from line to line or string to string .. so another line could have "[45m" in it and "[1m" , the regex example you gave removes everything at the end :( ... AND the text "OK" could say "FAILED" or another status

Comment: @johnjohnson I updated my answer, which now passes the use case you described.  If you have other edge cases, then reveal them and maybe I can update my answer again.

Comment: cool thx, you know what :) I actually then fig it out, but i couldn't without your guidance first on the ?: that's where i was confusing myself i think. hey really appreciated it.

Comment: @johnjohnson Using `?:` inside a term in parenthesis just tells the regex engine _not_ to capture what is inside.  `(\[\d+m)` would match _and_ also capture what is inside parenthesis, but we can "turn off" the capture to make the match more efficient.